# Variable assignment to first item in IEnumerable does not work

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am attempting to assign the value `true` to a field in my collection of objects. I am using the `First()` method to retrieve the first object, and assign to it. In this example, I am assigning the value `true` to the `Show` variable. However, immediately after the assignment, it appears that `Show` variable is still `false`:

```
    public class CallerItem
    {
        public int IndexId;
        public string PhoneNumber;
        public bool ToInd;
        public bool Show;
    }

    public void myFunc() {
        var callers = dbCallerRecs.Select(x => new CallerItem() { IndexId = x.IndexId, PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber, ToInd = x.ToInd });
        var toCallers = callers.Where(x => x.ToInd);
        if (toCallers.Any())
        {
            toCallers.First().Show = true;
            Console.Log(toCallers.First().Show); //THIS LOGS 'false'. HOWEVER, IT SHOULD LOG 'true'
        }
    }
```

Is there something I am missing? Perhaps my understanding of the references returned from the `Where` clause is not right?

Comment: I'll say it again: *the value of a query expression is an object which represents the query*. It is not *the results of the query*. A query produces a result set every time it is enumerated.

Comment: That's a good way to think about it. Thanks.

Comment: One thing that used to really help me with understanding this stuff was https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof . I haven't used it recently, but in the early days it was very useful to visualise when it was running DB queries (which may have aided your understanding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (toCallers.Any())
{
    toCallers.First().Show = true;
    Console.Log(toCallers.First().Show); //THIS LOGS 'false'. HOWEVER, IT SHOULD LOG 'true'
}
```

Every time you call `.First()` you are [getting the first item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#immediate-query-execution). For some enumerables (e.g. `IQueryable`) it will return a **different** object every time.

The below code will call the method **only once** and thus avoid the issue. *Note also that I have used `FirstOrDefault` rather than `Any` **then** `First` - since the former will result in fewer DB queries (i.e. be faster).*

```
var caller = toCallers.FirstOrDefault().
if (caller != null)
{
    caller.Show = true;
    Console.Log(caller.Show);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was my understanding that `Where` returns a reference to the original object. Is my understanding of that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is not quite correct. Have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution - does that make sense? _`Where` is deferred, while `First` is immediate._

Answer (score 1):

```
var callers = dbCallerRecs.Select(x => new CallerItem() { IndexId = x.IndexId, PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber, ToInd = x.ToInd });
var toCallers = callers.Where(x => x.ToInd);
```

defines a query which is evaluated when some elements in the resulting `IEnumerable<CallerItem>` (or `IQueryable<CallerItem>` which implements `IEnumerable<CallerItem>`) is iterated. This happens three times in your code - when calling `Any` and both times you call `First` (assuming `.Any()` returns `true`).

The reason you see this behaviour is the two calls to `First` cause the query to be re-evaluated and a new object to be created for each call, so you're modifying a different object the one you end up logging.

One solution would be to eagerly evaluate the query:

```
var toCallers = callers.Where(x => x.ToInd).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was my understanding that `Where` returns a reference to the original object. And if that is the case, wouldn't I be modifying the underlying object, and not a copy? Is my understanding of that incorrect?

Comment: @mjwills - Possibly yes, you could use `.Take(1).ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @MattSpinks - No, `Select(...).Where(...)` will create a new sequence of `CallerItem`s every time the result sequence is iterated over (which `First` does).